# How can you give a function one parameter at a time?

Tags: c++

For example, I have a function:

```
void get(int a, char b, int c, float d, int e, char f)
```

I want to give the function just d, e and f. How can I pass them as parameters.

**Just the three of them**.

Comment: Not possible and doesn't make any sense. Why?

Comment: Are you wanting to [curry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) the function?

Comment: @BryanChen: With C++11 (or rather C++14), lots of things are now possible.

Comment: void get(int a, char b, int c, (float d = afunction(int i)), (int e = afunction(int j)), (char f = afunction(int j))); You can call the function directly within the parameter as long as these functions returns a name type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write an overload as shown below:

```
auto get(float d, int e, char f) -> std::function<void(int, char, int)>
{
   return [=](int a, char b, int c) { get(a,b,c, d,e,f); };
}
```

That is, this overload takes `d`, `e`, `f` *only* and returns a callable entity which takes *rest* of the arguments — this callable entity eventually invokes your `get()` function.

You can use it as:

```
auto partial_get = get(d,e,f); //pass d, e, f
//code
partial_get(a,b,c); //invoke partial_get() passing rest of the arguments!
```

Here `partial_get` is a callable enity which you can invoke anytime passing the rest of the arguments — `partial_get` eventually invokes your `get()` function passing all the required arguments.

Comment: With all due respect sir i'm a starter. I've just started learning OOP in C++ and i came across thee topic of function overloading. I don't really know about it. what i do know is that there is a simple way by using : operator in the function call with the variable name. I dont know the syntax but it can be done using :. Please correct me if iam wrong....

Comment: @HasanAfzal: I don't know which *"simple way"* you're talking about. The above answer provides simple solution as well. Just read about [Lambda in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11) and function overloading. That is it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to switch the parameters of the function and give default values to `a`, `b`, and `c`, you can do that.

```
void get( float d, int e, char f, int a = 10, char b='\n', int c=16);
```

Then, you can call the function with values of just `d`, `e`, and `f`.

```
get(5.0f, 20, '\t');
```

The above call is equivalent to

```
get(5.0f, 20, '\t', 10, '\n', 16);
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ These are the default value of `a`, `b`, and `c`.
```